# Jquery click event keeping an a tag in list highlighted

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to highlight an image when it is clicked, I want it to stay highlighted until something else is clicked.

I'm not sure what I'm missing I've the following HTML (ignoring head and the Navbar).

```css
a.selected {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
</html>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center" id="searchLogos">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <div class="col-search">
        <p>Highlight icon below to search one database</p>

        <div class="d-flex">
          <ul class="list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center" id="searchLogos">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="Img/Netflix_Logo_RGB.png" id='netflix' alt="Button to select netflix" style="width:75px;height:75px;">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="Img/prime-video-logo@logotyp.us.svg" alt="Button to select prime" style="width:75px;height:75px">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="Img/hulu-digital-blkgrn.png" alt="Button to select Hulu" style="width:75px;height:75px">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="Img/Disney+-Logo.wine.png" alt="Button to select Disney+" style="width:75px;height:75px">
              </a>
            </li>


          </ul>
          <script>
            $('#searchLogos a').click(function() {
              $('#searchLogos a').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
          </script>
        </div>
        <script>
        </script>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!--End container-->
  </div>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This will do the job $(this).toggleClass('selected');, you don't need this line $('#searchLogos a').removeClass('selected');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this script just after `jquery` script.

```
    <script>
        $('#searchLogos a').click(function() {
             $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
    </script>
```

If you take a look to your browser console, you will see an error like this:

> Error: $ is not defined

Comment: Thank you! Thats done the trick, should have known better